# How to boot into previous windows 10 drive from new computer shipped with windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-11

**Backstory**

- Currently running windows 10 on 2018 custom built pc (sata ssd)
- Bought new windows 11 PC from dell.com (m2 nvme)
- Hooked up old win 10 drive to new pc - getting boot errors

**Troubleshooting**

- old win 10 drive succesfully shows up as "drive D:" on new pc
- alienware boot options seem wonky but I can boot to `sata/EFI/bootx64.efi` which end in "no boot device available"
- windows 10 does not show as a boot option anywhere in windows 11 gui
- boot repair options offer no help
- no luck with win10 usb efi boot, does not allow update & keep files

**Question**

Considering the scenario I'm in, is it possible for me to boot into windows 10 on my old ssd? My hope is to clone my old win 10 ssd to my new m2 nvme.

Comment: Windows just doesn't like doing this. Drivers can be very specific to one computer. You really should have made the clone from the old machine, whilst booted to that drive. This would have allowed the cloning software to separate out "the OS & data" from "the stuff specific to that one computer" & provided a 'blank canvas' the new machine could boot from.

Comment: Also if you did not set up Windows 10 like Windows 11 must be, it may not start. I certainly agree about drivers.

Comment: Suggestion: 1. **Make a disk image** of the new PC's drive so that you can recover from errors and resell the laptop with Windows 11 later. 2. Downgrade from Windows 11 to 10 with Win 10 ISO -- see https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-downgrade-from-windows-11-to-windows-10/, https://www.techadvisor.com/article/744263/how-to-downgrade-from-windows-11-to-windows-10.html, or https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-11-downgrade/, for example. 3. Put old drive in PC or in an external USB enclosure (from US$12 and up)and salvage data and portable apps that did not require installation (e.g., Sumo).

Comment: Can't you only revert w11 to w10 if you upgraded from win 10 originally? In my case I received a new computer with a fresh win 11 install. Considering that MS has made this difficult what if I upgrade the old win 10 drive to win 11, can I then use that drive on my new computer ? From there I could seamlessly clone drives.